# React Native Toggle Style

Tags: react-native, button, audio, styles, expo

I have a button which first load the audio and play, and If I click on him, it pauses the music as I wanted:

```
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

    let playandpauseflag = 0;
    let loadsoundonceflag = false;

    async function loadsound(){ 
        try {
           await soundObject.loadAsync(require('./hello.mp3'));
        } catch (error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    };

    async function loadplayandpausesong(){
        //just load sound once
        if(loadsoundonceflag){
            await loadsound();
            loadsoundonceflag = false; //next time will not load the sound, just play
        }
        if(playandpauseflag == false){
            await soundObject.playAsync(); //play
            playandpauseflag = true;
        }else{ //not false next time (true)
            await soundObject.pauseAsync(); //pause
            playandpauseflag = false;
        }
    }
```

I would like to change his style according to 'play' or 'pause'.
This is the way I'm rendering the styles:

```
<FontAwesome5
     name="play" //if I put "pause" I'll have the 'pause' design that I want when I click to play the button
></FontAwesome5>
```

I tried name= playandpauseflag ? "pause" : "play", but it doesn't work correctly. It is a way, but it is bugging my loading application and I would like to know If I could do it by another way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). For example,

```js
const [playState, setPlayState] = useState('pause');

const onClick = () => {
    if (playState === 'play') {
      setPlayState('pause');
    } else {
      setPlayState('play');
    }
};

return (
    <FontAwesome5 name={playState}></FontAwesome5>
);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering. I will try and come back with the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use useState to store the value of "playandpauseflag"

```
const [playandpauseflag, setPlayandpauseflag] = useState(false);
```

in your loadplayandpausesong() function

```
async function loadplayandpausesong(){
        //just load sound once
        if(loadsoundonceflag){
            await loadsound();
            loadsoundonceflag = false; //next time will not load the sound, just play
        }
        if(playandpauseflag == false){
            await soundObject.playAsync(); //play
            setPlayandpauseflag = true; //setState
        }else{ //not false next time (true)
            await soundObject.pauseAsync(); //pause
            setPlayandpauseflag = false; //setState
        }
    }
```

After this your button do this

```
<FontAwesome5name={playandpauseflag ? "play" : "pause"}></FontAwesome5>
```